# Overtime calculator

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a payroll calculator in Java, however I have been running into issues calculating double pay. Here is my code:

```
if ( hoursWorked <= 36 ) {
      totalPay = (hourlyRate * hoursWorked);
} else if ( hoursWorked >= 37 && hoursWorked <= 40) {
      totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5);     
} else  //(hoursWorked > 41 ) {
      totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2); 
}
```

The overtime works however calculating double pay is resulting in underpayment.

Comment: would be easier if you sepparate the operations.

Comment: The hours 41+ are paid twice (once 1.5 and once 2) if the worker is working > 41h

Comment: Please explain further.

Comment: do a local variable:

int doublePay=(hoursWorked-41)*(hourlyRate*2)

Comment: Please post the inputs and outputs that make you think it results in underpayment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last else segment is wrong.(hoursWorked > 41) It should be:

```
else { totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + 
                  (41 - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + 
                  (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( hoursWorked <= 36 ) {
      totalPay = (hourlyRate * hoursWorked);
} else if ( hoursWorked >= 37 && hoursWorked <= 40) {
      totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5);     
} else  //(hoursWorked > 41 ) {
      totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + ((hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5))
      int doublePay=(hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2); 
      totalPay=totalPay+doublePay;

}
```

Comment: I know you copied the code from @Max, so this question is for him.  Is the last else for 41 or 42 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
int tier1 = 0;
int tier2 = 0;
int tier3 = 0;
if (hoursWorked <= 36)
{
    tier1 = hoursWorked;
}else if (hoursWorked <= 40)
{
    tier1 = 36;
    tier2 = hoursWorked - tier1;
}else{
    tier1 = 36;
    tier2 = 4;
    tier3 = hoursWorked - tier2 - tier1;
}
totalPay = tier1* hourlyRate + tier2 * hourlyRate * 1.5 + tier3 * hourlyRate * 2;
```